# Making custom templates for texmaker

Tags: texmaker, editors

I typically use TeXShop as my editor, and like being able to quickly access custom templates when I create a new document.  I'm going to be teaching a student of mine how to use LaTeX, but he can't use TeXShop.  He uses ubuntu, and installed texmaker (we wanted an editor that I could easily install on my Mac so I could play around with it and help him troubleshoot).

I've taught a few students how to use LaTeX, and find that one effective way to do this is for them to start from a very basic template, then build a custom preamble that includes some useful packages (e.g., showing them how to install hyperref both gives them a useful package and shows them how to install packages).  I also show them how to save this as their own custom template, helping them see how to customize their editor (typically TeXShop).  This gives them confidence to play around and use the editor.

**Here's my primary question**: is there a way to create templates for texmaker?  I can't see one, but perhaps I'm missing something.  The closest I've gotten is creating a "texmaker template" folder and using the "New by copying an existing file".  Maybe it's just a matter of getting used to it, but I don't find it as elegant or intuitive a solution.

**Follow up question**: are there other editors you might recommend we use?  As I said, I'm a TeXShop user, but find most editors work just fine.  I'm looking for something that we can both run (he's a ubuntu user), so when he emails me with questions I can use the same editor in case it's not a coding error.

Comment: related to your follow-up question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides

Comment: [TeXworks:Crossplatform IDE](http://www.tug.org/texworks/) has a [good collection of templates](http://i.stack.imgur.com/G7DPa.png) (but of most of them are either inside TeXLive/MacTeX/MiKTeX distro) or available online 1. http://www.latextemplates.com/ 2.https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/ 3. https://www.writelatex.com/templates 4.http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/ 5.http://www.howtotex.com/templates/. But remember none of the editors has _all_ templates `built-in` since one has to choose based on their own requirements/taste.

Comment: If you want students to produce high-quality output using LaTeX without effort, experiment LyX. Regarding the templates, this is my approach: *the first document is the template to the second*. Forces students to always check what they copy/paste from the template rather than press a magic button to fill in the preamble.

Comment: To answer your Q: There is a Quick `Wizard` -->`Quick Start` in TeXmaker to give a basic idea on LaTeX structure for simple documents, but one can use the online templates to start up fast and understand some basics.

Comment: Thanks everyone, very helpful.  juliohm, your approach is the same as mine and, like you, I find it works well.

Comment: @juliohm Wanna write up an answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B feel free to contribute one if you have something in mind. ;)

Answer (score 1):

In TeXmaker under "User" menu, you have "User tags", you can edit them with "Edit user tags", they fit in full preamble.

When you have one saved, you can use it as template, just press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>Fx</kbd>

It have limit to 10 user tags, so I don't see way to create more templates. Also, usually you use those user tags for shorter things, so you will probably have space for just a few templates.

Either way, it's not so elegant as you would hope, but conviniet and better than creating folder with templates.